# Столкнулся с проблемой выпуска игры в Google Play. Invalid Data safety form

Tags: c#, unity3d, google-play, release-management, google-console

[image: Сообщение об отказе]

В приложении используется реклама от unity ads, возможно из-за этого возникает такая проблема.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В консоли Google Play выберите своё приложение. Далее "Контент приложения" -> "Безопасность данных". Отметьте, что вы собираете "Идентификаторы устройства и другие идентификаторы". Правда, если у вас приложение включено в программу "Для всей семьи" или предназначено для детей младше 13 лет, то сбор идентификаторов недопустим.

P.S. также вам необходимо указать, если это ещё не сделано, что вы собираете и передаете третьим лицам информацию и, скорее всего, пользователи не могут запросить её удаление

[image: Вот так]